# Отображение разнотипных данных в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Существует задача: в одной и той же области интерфейса, как реакцию на некоторые действия пользователя, выводить табличные данные во многом разных типов. Разумном ли будет просто создать два элемента DataGrid привязанных каждый к своей коллекции и скрывать один в зависимости от показа другого? Или существует какая-нибудь возможность  задать два набора столбцов в зависимости от типа привязанных элементов? Или может быть существует какой-нибудь контрол  более подходящий для моей задачи?

Comment: Думаю разумно иметь модель для отображения одну, а в нее уже собирать данные разного типа

Comment: Если AutoGenerateColumns выставить в true,  DataGrid привязать к коллекции элементов определенного типа, то элементы другого типа в эту коллекцию уже не добавить, а если коллекция будет более абстрактного типа, допустим предка всех тех которые нужно отображать, то тогда столбцы будут генерироваться только для свойств этого абстрактного типа. А если явно задать все нужные столбцы, то при отображении второго типа, столбцы определенные для первого будут отображаться пустыми. спасибо за замечания.

Comment: Вам обязательно DataGrid? Или достаточно ItemsControl? Опишите свою задачу с более высокоуровневой точки зрения.

Comment: Мне нужно просто отобразить коллекцию элементов в табличном виде с заголовками столбцов. Свойства объектов, просто string и int. Возможность редактирования не требуется.

Comment: Задать 2 набора столбцов - это кодом нужно мудрить. Так что проще всего ContentControl с 2мя шаблонами и в каждом свой DataGrid

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте использовать так: `autoGenerateColumns = true`,

```
    dataGrid.ItemSource = null;
    dataGrid.ItemSource = list1;
    dataGrid.ItemSource = null;
    dataGrid.ItemSource = list2;
```

Comment: То есть, вы предлагаете устанавливать связи динамически в коде? До сих пор мне удавалось избегать обращение к view из view model и почему-то хотелось найти возможность не обращаться и дальше. Может быть это мое стремление не вполне обоснованно и разумнее действительно поменять связь, чем например испольовать два DataGrid?

Comment: я иногда обновляю динамически. если вы найдете решение, разместите его, пожалуйста, здесь. еще Вы могли бы разместить пример своего кода

Comment: если будете обновлять динамически, может пригодится                                     dataGrid.Refresh();